# JS: [Deprecation] Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm receiving the error in my project trying an Ajax request

> [Deprecation] Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is
>   deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's
>   experience.

```
function getReviews() {
var toReturn = $.ajax({
    url: 'API/reviews.json',
    async: false
}).responseJSON;
return toReturn;
}
```

I would like to know if there is a different way to write this to not have that error

Comment: Well... don't set async to false.  Use promises or callbacks to handle the response.

Comment: That's not an error, that's a *warning* message. But yes, it means what is says, don't use `async: false` and rewrite your code to deal with asynchrony.

Answer (score 5):

Synchronous XMLHttpRequest is very bad because they are blocking entire app while it's waiting for a response from the server so you never should be using them.

To make your request asynchronous remove `async` option and specify callback instead:

```js
function getReviews(cb) {
  $.ajax({
      url: 'API/reviews.json'
  }).done(cb);
}

getReviews(function(data) {
  // Access your data here
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Instead of taking a callback, better return the promise.

Comment: @KonstantinAzizov thank you! Could you please show me your example using my script how it is now so I can understand what I have to modify please:
[code](https://pastebin.com/NFTw59rJ)

Comment: @Jakub, here is an [updated code](https://pastebin.com/2mRfUKsY).

Comment: @Bergi, I agree that promises are better but I wasn't sure which version of jQuery Jakob is using and also for sake of simplicity I've used a callback interface.

Comment: @KonstantinAzizov thank you! That helps :)

Comment: You're welcome, don't forget to mark the answer as "Correct" if you found this useful so it won't be listed in "Unanswered" section.